# angular checkbox-list template-expanding directive with ng-repeat : how to specify name of data field and display field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a little template-expanding directive that displays a checklist (multiple checkboxes):

```
my.directive('checkList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { items: '=' },
        template: '<div class="flow"><p data-ng-repeat="item in items"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-attr-id="chk-{{item.state}}" data-ng-model="item.chosen"/>{{item.name}}</label></p></div>'

    };

});
```

with this markup:

```
       <check-list items='states' ></check-list>
```

Which produces something like this:

```
[ ] Alabama
[ ] Arkansas
[ ] Connecticut

etc
```

But I would like to be able to indicate which *property* of the object in my `items` array should be used for the `ng-attr-id`. Above it is "state", but I'd like to pass that name to the directive via the markup. I would also like to do the same with the property that is bound in `ng-model` (above it is "chosen") and for the display-value too (above it is "name").

How would those three field-names be passed to the directive?  And how do I refer to them in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an extra variable into the isolate scope for example:

```
.directive('checkList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { 
            items: '=', 
            key: '&'
        },
        template: '<div class="flow"><p ng-repeat="item in items"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-attr-id="chk-{{item[key]}}" data-ng-model="item.chosen"/>{{item.name}}</label></p></div>'

    };    
});
```

and then in the html:

```
<check-list items='states' key="name"></check-list>
```

Note that in the template I've changed the object notation from item.name to item[key]

http://jsfiddle.net/b6ww0rx8/9/